# Inno Setup - Hiding the progress bar on install page

Tags: installation, progress-bar, inno-setup

I would like to hide the progress bar on the *Installing* page.

Is it even possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply hide the progress bar control:

```pascal
[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Visible := False;
end;
```

[image]